# Razor Page Project consuming a WEB API Project (.NET 6)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, razor, .net-6.0

I have a little problem using Razor pages consuming a Web Api Data and I don´t know how to start

In this moment I have two separate projects (the Client Project which is the Razor Project and the Server Project which is the Web Api) both are Net 6 projects.

The Server Project have some controllers (like a login or a createAccount) but I need a UI to show this controllers. So my idea is using a razor page but I don´t know how to start and how the Client Project consume the data from a Web Api

And also what are the extra code I need to put in the Program.cs so I can "connect" both of the Server and the Client projects.

Any help is welcome and sorry if my English is not that good